# Angular 2 Jasmine unable to test form submit

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Hi I am writing unit test case in jasmine. I am new to jasmine. I have one form in html and I am trying to write unit test case for this.

Below is my html code for form.

```
<form *ngIf="formResetToggle" class="form-horizontal" name="tenantEditorForm" #f="ngForm" novalidate
      (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid ? saveTenant() :
      (!tenantname.valid && showErrorAlert('Tenant name is required', 'Please enter a name for the tenant'));">

</form>
```

Below is the spec.

```
it('Save Tenant', fakeAsync(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        spyOn(component, 'saveTenant');
        let submitButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#saveTenant'));
        submitButton.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.saveTenant).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

This spec gives me error

> Expected spy saveTenant to have been called.

Can someone help me to figure it out the issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is caused because `debugElement.triggerEventHandler` methods triggers event handlers that were registered on **current** `debugElement` while you want to handle submit event on `form`.

In this case I would suggest you using native click event instead.

```
submitButton.nativeElement.click();
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between nativeElement.click() and event handler's click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425635/what-is-the-difference-between-nativeelement-click-and-event-handlers-click)

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/w1QavYuOxfgbplWzEHvQ?p=preview)**

Comment: Check my added example