# While testing angular app for the functionality "when button is clicked the count will be incremented and displayed in h2"

Tags: angular, npm, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test

When button is clicked the count will be incremented and at the same time the count will be displayed in the html page in angular. For this condition I wrote the unit test using jasmine + Karma runner. But the expected value is not equal.

In testing : debug element module is used.

**html code:**

```html
<button id="button1" (click)="count()">Click</button>
<h2>{{cnt}}</h2>
```

**ts code:**

```ts
cnt:number = 0;
count()
{
  this.cnt+=1;
}
```

**spec file:**

```js
it("check events with debugelement",()=>{
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      debug = fixture.debugElement;
      const h2 = debug.query(By .css('h2'));
      const btn = debug.query(By .css('#button1'));
      btn.triggerEventHandler('click',{});
      fixture.detectChanges();
      let x = component.cnt;
      let y = parseInt(h2.nativeElement.innerText);
      expect(x).toBe(y);
    })
```

**error:**

> `Expected 0 to be 1.`

"I am getting different values". Can I know what mistake I have done?.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is not having any error

Instead of defining `fixture` inside the `it()` block you can use `beforeEach`

```
beforeEach(() => {
  // code executed before every 'it' block
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
})
```

Also assign `component` variable with `fixture.componentInstance`

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you're querying for `h2`'s value too early.

Follow my comments for a detailed explanation.

```
it("check events with debugelement",()=>{
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      debug = fixture.debugElement;
      const h2 = debug.query(By .css('h2'));
      // h2's value here is 0
      // !! change the following 2 lines !!
      const btn = debug.query(By .css('#button1')).nativeElement;
      btn.click();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      let x = component.cnt;
      let y = parseInt(h2.nativeElement.innerText);
      // y is zero here since you didn't query for the new/updated h2
      const updatedh2 = debug.query(By.css('h2'));
      let z = parseInt(updatedh2.nativeElement.innerText);
      // z should be one now
      expect(x).toBe(z);
    })
```

Comment: h2 value is working fine but the value of the variable x is zero even after triggering the event of the click . result: x = 0 & z =1 .

Comment: Ok, check my edits. Try using `btn.click()` instead of `triggerEventHandler`.

Comment: Yeah it works fine with the click but it fails for `triggerEventHandler` can I know the reason why it isn't working ?

Comment: I think this answer explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445291/7365461